# How can I run two different view files at a time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. So I'm getting some issues. I have a controller and having two `ActionResult` methods in this controller. I made two different view files and I just want to know that how can I execute both view files together.

[image: This my Solution explorer]

Comment: It seems to be that you might use [Partial views in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1)